# Redux state set to null on page reload

Tags: redux

I am working on a project where after successful login, I dispatched an action to redux state and setting Redux state to **LoggedIn**. But when I refresh the page, all the values in the redux state become null. Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux is an in-memory store. If you want to persist it over page refreshes, you have to add a library such as [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)